# Subset function in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on writing a subset function and I have succeeded in doing so. 
Here's my function which implements member function:

```
 member( X, [ X | T ] ).
 member( X, [ _ | T ] ) :- member( X, T ).

 subset([], _).
 subset([H|T1], T2) :-
    member(H, T2),
    subset(T1, T2). 
 subset([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    \+ member(H1, T2),
    subset([H1|T1], T2).
```

My question is, is there a better way to write this function using the member function of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third clause of `subset/3` does not make sense and i think that it should be removed.
If `H1` is not a member of `T2`, then the recursive call `subset([H1|T1], T2)` will obviously don't succeed either.

Aside from that, the first two clauses seem the way to go.